# How to plot results from functions?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Having data in Series and trying to calculate certain values but when trying to plot them it does not work.

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# import numpy as np
import numpy as np
  
# simple array
data = np.array([0,0,1,1,1])
  
ser = pd.Series(data)
print('The mean is ' + str(ser.mean()))

# find the variance
print('The variance is ' + str(ser.var()))

ser.mean().plot.bar(rot=0) # Attempt to use barplot
ser.var().plot.bar(rot=0) # Attempt to use barplot
```

The above give the following error:

```
The mean is 0.6
The variance is 0.30000000000000004
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

It would be cool to show both values in a single plot also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function which you are trying to use is only available for pandas DataFrame/Series, but you can't use it to plot 'float', 'int' values.

For this case, either store the mean and variance values to an dataframe/series as follows

```
d = [ser.mean(),ser.var()]
df = pd.Series(d) #pd.DataFrame(d) also works
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=1)
ax.set_xticklabels(['Mean','Variance'])
```

or you can use other packages to plot a bar chart.

Comment: How can it show different bar names beneath each bar? It currently says 0 under the one and 1 under the other?

Comment: check the edits in the answer.

Comment: what does the rot parameter do?

Comment: rotates the labels, maybe try rot=0 to see it for yourself.